# Python : 'Can't assign to operator' Syntax error

Tags: python, arrays, syntax-error, assign

I'm trying to write a program where test scores are collected in lists and then certain factors such as highest scores are outputted. However when I try to assign intH1 (highest result for test 1) I get the above error. The line is `intH1 = score1_list[intCount] and strHN1 = name_list[intCount]`

```
if score1_list[intCount] > intH1:
     intH1 = score1_list[intCount] and strHN1 = name_list[intCount]
if score2_list[intCount] > intH2:
     intH2 = score2_list[intCount] and strHN2 = name_list[intCount]
if score3_list[intCount] > intH3:
     intH3 = score3_list[intCount] and strHN3 = name_list[intCount]
if total_list[intCount] > intHT:
     intHT = total_list[intCount] and strHNT = name_list[intCount]`
```

Comment: What did you hope `intH1 = score1_list[intCount] and strHN1 = name_list[intCount]` would achieve? That's not valid Python.

Comment: I was trying to change `intH1` to `score1_list[intCount]` if `intH1` was smaller than `score1_list[intCount]` and also change `strHN1` (the student name) to `name_list[intCount]` so that they could be outputted together to say 'The highest score for test 1 was ... by ...'. I apologies for my terrible code, I've only been learning Python for a couple of weeks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `and` to assign two variables. Python parses your assignment as:

```
intH1 = (score1_list[intCount] and strHN1) = name_list[intCount]
```

trying to assign the result of the `name_list[intCount]` expression to both `intH1` and to `score1_list[intCount] and strHN1`. `and` is an operator, which can only be used in *expressions*, but assignment is a *statement*. Statements can contain expressions, expressions cannot contain statements.

This is why the [defined grammar for assignments](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) uses the grammar entities *expression_list`and`yield_expression`, two expression forms you can use, only in the part to the right of the`=` equals sign:

```
assignment_stmt ::=  (target_list "=")+ (expression_list | yield_expression)
```

while the `target_list` definition doesn't allow any use of arbitrary expressions.

Use *separate lines* for assignment:

```
intH1 = score1_list[intCount]
strHN1 = name_list[intCount]
```

or use tuple assignment:

```
intH1, strHN1 = score1_list[intCount], name_list[intCount]
```

Comment: Thanks that's fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Each branch of the `if` does two assignments. You don't need an `and` between them, you just need to separate them to two statements:

```
if score1_list[intCount] > intH1:
    intH1 = score1_list[intCount]
    strHN1 = name_list[intCount]
if score2_list[intCount] > intH2:
    intH2 = score2_list[intCount]
    strHN2 = name_list[intCount]
if score3_list[intCount] > intH3:
    intH3 = score3_list[intCount]
    strHN3 = name_list[intCount]
if total_list[intCount] > intHT:
    intHT = total_list[intCount]
    strHNT = name_list[intCount]
```